# How to get the extract the Time zone( (GMT+05:30) from systemTimeZone(NSTimeZone)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Can anyone get me the idea in extracting the timezone from `systemTimeZone(NSTimeZone)`

I have added the sample along with this.

```
NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@" - current  local timezone  is  %@",localTime);
```

Im getting Out put as follows - current local timezone is Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset `19800`

From above out put how to get the zone alone .ie- only GMT+05:30

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Thanks Toon....i like your network profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you what you want,

```
NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@" - current  local timezone  is  %@",[localTime abbreviation]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much...Thilina. it's best answer/example for my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSLog(@" - current  local timezone  is  %@",[localTime abbreviation]);
```

I think it is helpful.